# Form issue when trying to create a checkbox with CollectionType calling to another FromType (cross entities situation)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

This case is a case study, I'm trying to resolve this issue in order to explain how to organize entities and create forms to my students.

I have this singular relation between 3 of my entities :

Protagonist <--(OneToMany)--> EventRegistration <--(ManyToOne)--> Event

Which could not be transformed as a many to many relation because there are some columns inside the EventRegistration table :

Protagonist :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProtagonistRepository")
 */
class Protagonist
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $japaneseName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80, nullable=true)
     */
    private $picture;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80, nullable=true)
     */
    private $background;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="protagonists")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tag", mappedBy="protagonists")
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Registration", mappedBy="protagonist")
     */
    private $registrations;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isAlive;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", mappedBy="protagonists")
     */
    private $events;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventRegistration", mappedBy="protagonist")
     */
    private $eventRegistrations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->registrations = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->events = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->eventRegistrations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJapaneseName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->japaneseName;
    }

    public function setJapaneseName(?string $japaneseName): self
    {
        $this->japaneseName = $japaneseName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPicture(): ?string
    {
        return $this->picture;
    }

    public function setPicture(?string $picture): self
    {
        $this->picture = $picture;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBackground(): ?string
    {
        return $this->background;
    }

    public function setBackground(?string $background): self
    {
        $this->background = $background;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Tag[]
     */
    public function getTags(): Collection
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag): self
    {
        if (!$this->tags->contains($tag)) {
            $this->tags[] = $tag;
            $tag->addProtagonist($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTag(Tag $tag): self
    {
        if ($this->tags->contains($tag)) {
            $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
            $tag->removeProtagonist($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Registration[]
     */
    public function getRegistrations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->registrations;
    }

    public function addRegistration(Registration $registration): self
    {
        if (!$this->registrations->contains($registration)) {
            $this->registrations[] = $registration;
            $registration->setProtagonist($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRegistration(Registration $registration): self
    {
        if ($this->registrations->contains($registration)) {
            $this->registrations->removeElement($registration);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($registration->getProtagonist() === $this) {
                $registration->setProtagonist(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsAlive(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isAlive;
    }

    public function setIsAlive(?bool $isAlive): self
    {
        $this->isAlive = $isAlive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Event[]
     */
    public function getEvents(): Collection
    {
        return $this->events;
    }

    public function addEvent(Event $event): self
    {
        if (!$this->events->contains($event)) {
            $this->events[] = $event;
            $event->addProtagonist($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEvent(Event $event): self
    {
        if ($this->events->contains($event)) {
            $this->events->removeElement($event);
            $event->removeProtagonist($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|EventRegistration[]
     */
    public function getEventRegistrations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->eventRegistrations;
    }

    public function addEventRegistration(EventRegistration $eventRegistration): self
    {
        if (!$this->eventRegistrations->contains($eventRegistration)) {
            $this->eventRegistrations[] = $eventRegistration;
            $eventRegistration->setProtagonist($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEventRegistration(EventRegistration $eventRegistration): self
    {
        if ($this->eventRegistrations->contains($eventRegistration)) {
            $this->eventRegistrations->removeElement($eventRegistration);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($eventRegistration->getProtagonist() === $this) {
                $eventRegistration->setProtagonist(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

EventRegistration :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRegistrationRepository")
 */
class EventRegistration
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz")
     */
    private $registrationDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Protagonist", inversedBy="eventRegistrations")
     */
    private $protagonist;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", inversedBy="eventRegistrations")
     */
    private $event;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRegistrationDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->registrationDate;
    }

    public function setRegistrationDate(\DateTimeInterface $registrationDate): self
    {
        $this->registrationDate = $registrationDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProtagonist(): ?Protagonist
    {
        return $this->protagonist;
    }

    public function setProtagonist(?Protagonist $protagonist): self
    {
        $this->protagonist = $protagonist;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEvent(): ?Event
    {
        return $this->event;
    }

    public function setEvent(?Event $event): self
    {
        $this->event = $event;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Event :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRepository")
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz", nullable=true)
     */
    private $start_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz", nullable=true)
     */
    private $end_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Protagonist", inversedBy="events")
     */
    private $protagonists;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventRegistration", mappedBy="event")
     */
    private $eventRegistrations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->protagonists = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->eventRegistrations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->start_date;
    }

    public function setStartDate(?\DateTimeInterface $start_date): self
    {
        $this->start_date = $start_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEndDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->end_date;
    }

    public function setEndDate(?\DateTimeInterface $end_date): self
    {
        $this->end_date = $end_date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Protagonist[]
     */
    public function getProtagonists(): Collection
    {
        return $this->protagonists;
    }

    public function addProtagonist(Protagonist $protagonist): self
    {
        if (!$this->protagonists->contains($protagonist)) {
            $this->protagonists[] = $protagonist;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProtagonist(Protagonist $protagonist): self
    {
        if ($this->protagonists->contains($protagonist)) {
            $this->protagonists->removeElement($protagonist);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|EventRegistration[]
     */
    public function getEventRegistrations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->eventRegistrations;
    }

    public function addEventRegistration(EventRegistration $eventRegistration): self
    {
        if (!$this->eventRegistrations->contains($eventRegistration)) {
            $this->eventRegistrations[] = $eventRegistration;
            $eventRegistration->setEvent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEventRegistration(EventRegistration $eventRegistration): self
    {
        if ($this->eventRegistrations->contains($eventRegistration)) {
            $this->eventRegistrations->removeElement($eventRegistration);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($eventRegistration->getEvent() === $this) {
                $eventRegistration->setEvent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I can access a collection of eventRegistrations with my Protagonist and Event entity, and I can access the protagonist and event with my EventRegistration entity.

The issue crops up when I try to create a checkbox with all the events available for the protagonist : I don't have any attribute that allows me to make a collection of those events :

ProtagonistType

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Event;
use App\Entity\EventRegistration;
use App\Entity\Protagonist;
use App\Entity\Tag;
use App\Repository\EventRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class ProtagonistType
 * @package App\Form
 */
class ProtagonistType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('japaneseName', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('picture', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('background', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('isAlive', CheckboxType::class)
             ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'expanded' => true,
                 'multiple' => false
            ])
            ->add('tags', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Tag::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
            **->add('eventRegistrations', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => EventRegistrationType::class
            ])**
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Protagonist::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

EventRegistrationType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Event;
use App\Entity\EventRegistration;
use App\Repository\EventRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class EventRegistrationType
 * @package App\Form
 */
class EventRegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('event', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Event::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => EventRegistration::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The only effective solution I found is to create a ManyToMany relation between Protagonist and Event, then set another Registration table which is on a ManyToOne relation with Protagonist in order to get the protagonists registrations.

Still I'd like to make this many to many relation with extra fields works, I'm all ears for any solution you'd get to solve this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Some theory

**Entities** are your models, business objects that have identities, data, behavior.

They are the heart, building blocks of your business model.

When we design entities - in the first place we should consider them as objects, that have their own shape and responsibilities instead of them being just containers for data stored in a database. Also, we should care about proper relations between entities.

Ideally, entities should always be valid. If so - they can be persisted at any time.

---

**Persistence** is a separate concern.

In general case, it's even not necessary for entities to be persisted into a database. They could just be persisted in memory, file system, key-value storage etc.

---

**Forms** is also a separate concern that is closer to working with user interfaces.

Forms help us to render user interface, translate requests from users to some **structures** of known shape that is easier to work with, than with raw data from requests, and validate this submitted data.

These structures are just containers for data retrieved from requests, they should not have any behavior.

These structures can be invalid at certain times.

## What about the issue described?

So making entities playing roles of these forms underlying data structures might be not the best idea ever.

It's just clearly mixing of concerns and rigid coupling between different layers.

That is why you're having these issues.

So instead of using `EventRegistration` class as a `data_class` for `EventRegistrationType` and `Protagonist` - for `ProtagonistType` - consider creating separate data structures. Propagate submitted data to entities only when it's successfully validated.

---

Some useful links to read more on the topic (though the author calls underlying structures - commands somewhy):

- [Decoupling (Symfony2) Forms from Entities](http://verraes.net/2013/04/decoupling-symfony2-forms-from-entities/)
- [Form, Command, and Model Validation](http://verraes.net/2015/02/form-command-model-validation/)

Other useful topics:

- [The Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)
- [Domain-Driven Design in PHP](https://leanpub.com/ddd-in-php)